# G++: Trying to add include and lib to default directory

Tags: c++, linker

I've compiled Google C++ Test.  I'm now trying to add it to my g++ installation (on Cygwin) such that I don't have to specify `-I`, `-L`, and `-l` for every project.  The steps I did were:

1. I put a symlink in /usr/local/include to GTEST_ROOT/include/gtest
2. I put symlinks in /usr/local/lib to the libs in GTEST_ROOT/lib (libgtest.la  libgtest_main.la)
3. I wrote a proof program to test the setup

The test program compiles fine with `g++ -c proof.cpp` but `g++ proof.cpp` gives errors during the linking, saying that the gtest references can't be found.

Using grep to search my GTEST_ROOT for the required references, I found them in additional libs in GTEST_ROOT/lib/.libs (libgtest.a  libgtest.la  libgtest.lai  libgtest_main.a  libgtest_main.la  libgtest_main.lai)

Due to time constraints, I got it to work using the following command `g++ -LGTEST_ROOT/lib/.libs -lgtest proof.cpp` and I've put this in a makefile.

However, I'm still trying to get my setup such that `g++ proof.cpp` would just work.  What am I missing?

Thanks to Matt, I understand now that I cannot drop the `-lgtest`.  I would like to at least get rid of the `-LGTEST_ROOT/lib/.libs`.  I've added symlinks to the additional `.a` and `.lai` files provided.  However, `g++ proof.cpp -lgtest` now gives me the linker error: `cannot find -lgtest`

NOTE: symlinking the libs in GTEST_ROOT/lib/.libs still does not give the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll always need to pass `-lgtest` to your final compile/link step<sup>1</sup>. GCC will not search all the libraries in its search path for the symbols that it is missing (that would be way too expensive).

The library files themselves (`.so` or `.a`) need to be in the `/usr/local/lib/` directory, or a symlink to those files. Symlinking a directory there will not work.

<sup>1</sup><sub>well, that's not technically true. You could modify your spec file, but don't do that.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, Mat.  I had symlinks to `libgtest.la` and `libgtest_main.la` (not the directory).  At your suggestion, I've added symlinks to the `.a` and `.lai` files (there were no `.so` files) too.  So I would expect that `g++ proof.cpp -lgtest` that would work but instead I get a `cannot find -lgtest` error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing all the symlinks _except_ the `.a` ones. BTW doesn't gtest have a `make install` target? You shouldn't have to do any of this by hand, the make process should handle the install part (and fixing up the `.la` files for install).

Comment: Thanks again, Mat.  No change when removing all but the `.a` files. And gtest's `make install` usefully tells you to read the README, which has no instructions regarding what to do with the libs.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to specifiy this parameter if you want to lik against it - that's what Makefile is for - so you don't need to type those long lines every compilation. If you want you can also use LDFLAGS enviroment variable to store those for you, but then you will get it linked to every executable that you compile - this is definitely not a good idea.